# sql repeat regex pattern unlimited times

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2017

I need to select where column contains numbers only and ends with a hyphen

I'm running SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

I have tried:

```
select * from [table] where [column] like '[0-9]*-'
select * from [table] where [column] like '[0-9]{1,}-'
select * from [table] where [column] like '[0-9]{1,2}-'
```

none of these work. The expression ([0-9]*-) works in any regex tester I've run it against, SQL just doesn't like it, nor the other variations I've found searching.

Comment: Are you using SQL server?

Comment: Yes. And I'm running SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter where any but the last character are not numbers and the last is a dash.  DATALENGTH/2 assumes NVARCHAR type.  If you're using VARCHAR, just use DATALENGTH

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    [table]
WHERE 
    [column] like '%-'
    AND
    LEFT([column], (datalength([column])/2)-1) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: This except no /2

/2 returned 80000000a- when i tested it, but removing the /2 worked. Thank you.

Comment: That means your column is varchar.  DATALENGTH is 2 bytes per character for NVARCHAR (UNICODE) and 1 for VARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left()` and `right()` functions as below :

```
with [table]([column]) as
(
 select '1234-'  union all
 select '{123]'  union all
 select '1234'   union all
 select '/1234-' union all
 select 'test-'  union all
 select '1test-' union all
 select '700-' 
)
select *
  from [table] 
 where left([column],len([column])-1) not like '%[^0-9]%'
   and right([column],1)='-';

 column
 ------
 1234-
 700-
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=815cb194646c06f1580e43cc6dbc2697)</kbd>

Comment: I tested that with these values
test-
1test-
700-

And it returned
1test-
700-

I only want 700-

Comment: @KnightsOfTheRoun recently I could see your comment, you're right. Fixed the style of regex in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not support regular expressions -- just very limited extensions to `like` functionality.

One method is:

```
where column like '%-' and
      column not like '%[^0-9]%-'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH [table] AS (
    SELECT '-' as [column] UNION ALL
    SELECT '1-' as [column] UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-' as [column] UNION ALL
    SELECT '1234-' as [column] UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-4' as [column] UNION ALL
    SELECT '-1234' as [column] 
)
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE [column] like '[0-9]' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', LEN([column])-2) + '-'
```

Returns

```
1-
123-
1234-
```